# Customise mat-paginator to show total number of records

Tags: angular-material

I'm using mat-paginator provided by Angular Material Design UI framework.

I currently have the setup shown below but in addition to this information I want to be able to display total number of records (i.e. 45) with in the paginator block shown below.

[image: pagination]

Response I get from the back-end service is as follows;

```
page: {size: 5, totalElements: 45, totalPages: 9, number: 0}
```

I have used this information to setup the mat-paginator properties as shown below.

```
  <mat-paginator #paginator
    [length]=result.pages
    [pageSize]=result.pageSize
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]"
    [pageIndex]=result.page
    (page)="getNext($event)"
    showFirstLastButtons>
  </mat-paginator>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given below response from backend service...

```
page: {size: 5, totalElements: 45, totalPages: 9, number: 0}
```

the following definition should be sufficent:

```
<mat-paginator #paginator
    [length]="result.page.totalElements"
    [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20, 50, 100]"
    (page)="getNext($event)"
    showFirstLastButtons="true">
</mat-paginator>
```